# Gather Outlook contacts list

Tags: c++, windows, outlook, mapi

Someone can tell me what API's to use to gather outlook contacts list ?
I saw some people that asked similar thing used something called 'MPI', but i dont know how to use that functions set in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very nice example with code in C++ can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3695/Importing-contacts-from-Outlook)

Answer (score 1):

It's not MPI but rather [MAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_Application_Programming_Interface). It's COM-based.

The documentation for it [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765775.aspx).