# Export outlook contacts

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, outlook, mapi

I already asked this here -> [Gather Outlook contacts list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774329/gather-outlook-contacts-list)

But the solution using MAPI doesnt looks bad, its very dependent on some Outlook lib's which are not present on every PC also they have different location based on Win version and Outlook version.

So isnt there any other way to get contacts info other than using MAPI ?
Arent the contacts saved in files where i can read them from or something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn;t this just reasking your previous question, and so making it a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own Outlook pst parser based on [the PST Format](http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/rn01re05.html). Contacts are also available in this file.

Comment: this URL (http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/) also gives some hints about additionals mechanisms, utilities...

Comment: another way would be to use WMI (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/26/use-powershell-to-data-mine-your-outlook-inbox.aspx) to query Outlook contacts

Comment: I dont find .pst file on my PC... i have Outlook version that comes with Windows XP. I think it saves information in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Microsoft\Address Book\Administrator.wab

Comment: ok, then create your WAB wrapper based on the documented - legacy - COM (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629361(v=vs.85) WAP interfaces

Comment: I see i can use the WAB API set for older versions of Outlook, but for the newer versions i have to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735778(v=vs.85) i never used COM, do you know any good examples to help me ?

Comment: You might use this link (http://www.theeggeadventure.com/QandA/WAB.htm) as good starting point

Comment: Isnt there some command line utility for windows that can export outlook ?

Comment: WAB is legacy...Google on this.

Comment: This is not a command line tool, but maybe it helps - Exporting OE's Addressbook (Text/CSV) (http://www.steve.maurer.net/tutorials/email_tutorials/export_addressbookCSV.htm)

Answer (score 0):

MAPI is COM based so you code shouldn't care where it's located or whihc version is installed, it'll just use whichever version is available (Assuming you build against the lowest supported version).

An alternative is to use the Outlook object model which gives access to the internals of Outlook but works in almost exactly the same way as MAPI.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3695/Importing-contacts-from-Outlook <- i tried to compile this on Win XP which has only the Outlook that comes default with it, i have MSOUTL.OLB missing... what i have to download to be able to compile against the lowest possible version ?

Comment: Windows doesn't come with Outlook. If you mean Outlook Express, that is an entirely different application.